# Difficulty Understanding C Pointer Syntax

Tags: c, pointers

Given the following C definitions:

```
#define SYNC_BYTE_1                         0x5A
#define SYNC_BYTE_2                         0xA5
```

and pointer declaration:

```
UINT8   *pCommandData;
pCommandData = GetCommandBufferPointer( LINGO_GENERAL, stringLength + 3 );
```

What exactly are the following two lines of code doing with the pointer?

```
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_2;
```

I specifically don't understand the use of `*` and the `++` in this instance. If the pointer's address is being incremented shouldnt the `*` be replaced with a `&`?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, this has been very helpful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pCommandData` is a pointer to some piece of memory. The first line

```
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;
```

sets the value at that address to `0x5A`, and then increments the pointer `pCommandData` to the next address. The next line

```
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_2;
```

works similarly: it sets the value that `pCommandData` points to, to `0xA5`, and then increments the pointer to the next address.

Perhaps a picture would be useful. Before either line executes, the memory in the neighborhood of wherever `pCommandData` points to might look like this:

```
                    |        |
                    +--------+
pCommandData -----> |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
```

After `*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;`:

```
                    |        |
                    +--------+
pCommandData --+    |  0x5A  |
               |    +--------+
               +--> |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
```

And after `*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_2;`:

```
                    |        |
                    +--------+
pCommandData --+    |  0x5A  |
               |    +--------+
               |    |  0xA5  |
               |    +--------+
               +--> |        |
                    +--------+
                    |        |
```

Comment: Thanks for the diagram @Matt Ball, it makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm a very visual person so pictures go a long way for me.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
UINT8 *pCommandData;
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
UINT8 *pCommandData;
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_1;
pCommandData++;
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_2;
pCommandData++;
```

or:

```
UINT8 *pCommandData;
pCommandData[0] = SYNC_BYTE_1;
pCommandData[1] = SYNC_BYTE_2;
pCommandData += 2;
```

Comment: And you ought to note that this is UB, because the pointer is invalid.

Comment: @Tomalak: I assume that some code has been ignored to simplify the question.

Comment: @Matt: Not sure when that mistake made it into my memory. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The construct of:

> *pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;

Simply means set the value pointed to by `pCommandData` to `SYNC_BYTE_1`, then increment the pointer to point to the next location. Since `pCommandData` is a pointer to an unsigned 8-bit integer, that means it will be incremented to point to the next (following) 8-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer itself is being incremented, to point to the next byte.

This works exactly like if it had been written:

```
*pCommandData = value;
pCommandData++;
```

You would use `&pCommandData` to get the address of the pointer itself, but that is not what happens here. Using `*pCommandData` gives you access to the object the pointer points to (if any :-).

Comment: What about the OP's question about `&`?

Comment: @Robert - Ok, but that's not needed as the pointer's address isn't involved. It is the pointer's **value** that is used.

Comment: @Tomalak - The pointer is of course properly initialized in the part of the code that was left out. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak - We can only guess. I have added that to my answer. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: Best to guess on the side of caution, IMO.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I left the initializaion out for simplicity. Maybe I should add it to the question body ?

Comment: @SamanB: Yes; it changes the meaning of the program in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of:

```
*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1;
```

is:

```
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_1;
 pCommandData++;
```

Comment: Actually, I think ++ has a higher precedence. If * had a higher precedence, you would get the value pointed to by the pointer being incremented. See http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm

Comment: But you do get the value pointed to by the pointer being incremented.

Comment: The postfix increment actually executes first. The effect of the increment is to increment the pointer. The return value of the postfix increment is to return the unincremented pointer. It actually happens first. The problem with your post is that the `*` operator has less precedence than the `++`.

Comment: @Lee-Man: Note that you are saying exactly the same thing as I do.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk of data pCommandData is pointing to is set to `0x5A`, then the pointer is set to the next byte which is itself set to `0xA5`. In the end the pointer is set to the next byte in the memory.

You can rewrite the code to something like this:

```
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_1;
pCommandData = pCommandData + 1;
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_2;
pCommandData = pCommandData + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's putting sync byte values into pCommandData, that's why you see *pCommandData, afterwards you increment it to go to next byte.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
*p++ = rval ;
```

is read as

*(p++) = rval ;

which instructs the compiler to

1. save the value of `p` as p1.
2. increment p
3. Dereference p1
4. Assign the value of `rval` to the dereferenced thingy.

edited to note: I'd never write `*p++` as it's very confusing unless you're clear on operator precedence. I'd make my intent clear by explicitly writing `*(p++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix `++` has a higher precedence than unary `*`, so expressions of the form `*p++` are parsed as `*(p++)`; IOW, you're dereferencing the *result* of `p++`.

What does that mean in the context of your code?

Given the expression `*pCommandData++ = SYNC_BYTE_1`, here's a rough explanation of what's happening:

1. The expression `pCommandData++` is evaluated.  The *result* of the expression is the current value of `pCommandData`, which is a pointer value.  As a *side effect*, the value of `pCommandData` is updated.  Exactly when this update occurs is not specified beyond the fact that it must occur before the next sequence point.
2. The *result* of the expression `pCommandData++` is dereferenced using the `*` operator.  The result of this larger expression is an *lvalue* (an expression that refers to an object in memory such that we can read or modify that object).
3. We assign the value SYNC_BYTE_1 to the lvalue that was computed in step 2.

Semantically, it's the same as writing:

```
*pCommandData = SYNC_BYTE_1;
 pCommandData++;
```